# Many if statements

Tags: java

how to check three other  objects property? i need to check if it's not equals null, for each three property and then do something with each three statements.

```
if(current.getValue()>0)

{
  serie = fChart
      .createSeries()
      .setName(current.getLabel())
      .setPoints(
          new Number[]{
              {t.getTime(),
                  current.getValue()}
              Chart.addSeries(serie);
```

i need to check it for the next two statements such

```
if(current1.getValue()>0)
then do something for the serie1, and 
if(current2.getValue()>0)
then do something for the serie2
```

i tried it to write like:

```
if (current.getValue() > 0) {
  serie = fChart
      .createSeries()
      .setName(current.getLabel())
      .setPoints(
          new Number[] {
              {
                  t.getTime(),
                  current.getValue() }


              Chart.addSeries(serie);
  }
  if (current1.getValue() > 0) {
    serie1 = fChart
        .createSeries()
        .setName(current.getLabel1())
        .setPoints(
            new Number[] {
                {t.getTime(),
                    current1.getValue1() }
                Chart.addSeries(serie1);
    }
    if (current2.getValue() > 0) {
      serie2 = fChart
          .createSeries()
          .setName(current.getLabel2())
          .setPoints(
              new Number[] {
                  {t.getTime(),
                      current2.getValue2() }
                  Chart.addSeries(serie2);
      }
```

but it doesnt seems to work, any suggestions?

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: Please format this code...

Comment: `but it doesnt seems to work` What is the problem?

Comment: I agree, I am getting a headache trying to match up the parenthesis.  Please fix the formatting and indentation.

Comment: uncaught exception escaped

Comment: Then you should also post the stack trace of your exception

Answer (score 1):

If I understand U right then U need something like this: if all three values less than '0' than do... If U need to do something when value don't equals null then replace `>` with `!=`

```
if (current.getValue() > 0 && current1.getValue() > 0 && current2.getValue > 0) {
   // some actions...
}
```

Comment: i need to proof if all three values >0 and then do for each three values different things

Comment: Oh my God! In this code program checks for all values > 0 and if they are then in IF body U need to write what will program do.

Comment: Kaly, you should improve your question instead of complaining the answers... You not even they what is not working. Is nothing happening? Or what?

Comment: sorry, there comes again uncaught exception escaped and  nothing happening

Comment: @Kaly, it wasn't your question. And U need to post stack-trace if U need help with this error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question fully, but here are my thoughts

Firstly, try to remove as much duplicate code as possible. Right now you're doing the exact same thing for each *currentX* which is a waste of screen space but is also bad for readability. Assuming *current*, *current1* and *current2* are of the same type, you could do something like this:

```
Object[] currents = [current, current1, current2];

for (Object cur : currents) {
    if (cur.getValue() != null && cur.getValue() > 0) {
        serie = fChart
        .createSeries()
        .setName(cur.getLabel())
        .setPoints(
            new Number[] {
                {
                    t.getTime(),
                    cur.getValue() 
                }
                Chart.addSeries(serie);
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the assigning of *serie*. I left it like that because of that.

Edit: -------------------

Based on feedback from the OP I came up with a version 2 of my answer.
Firstly, you had a syntax error in your code. That's most likely what caused your error.
Secondly;

```
if (current.getValue() != null && current.getValue() > 0 && current1.getValue() != null && current1.getValue() > 0 && current2.getValue() != null && current2.getValue() > 0) {
    serie = fChart
    .createSeries()
    .setName(cur.getLabel())
    .setPoints(
        new Number[] {
            {
                t.getTime(),
                cur.getValue() 
            }
            Chart.addSeries(serie);
        }
    )

    serie1 = fChart
    .createSeries()
    .setName(cur.getLabel1())
    .setPoints(
        new Number[] {
            {
                t.getTime(),
                current1.getValue1() 
            }
            Chart.addSeries(serie1);
        }
    )

    serie2 = fChart
    .createSeries()
    .setName(cur.getLabel2())
    .setPoints(
        new Number[] {
            {
                t.getTime(),
                current2.getValue2() 
            }
            Chart.addSeries(serie2);
        }
    )
}
```

This should fill your needs. If you still get any errors, please post them or be more specific of what you really want.

You could improve this by re-using the serie object instead of creating a new one for each operation, but for OP's understanding I left it like this.

Comment: Ah I see, my bad. Depending on the implementation of each getLabel() it could still be applicable. I'll leave it here in case it's still useful to OP or anyone else. Thanks.

Comment: yes i not call for all of these only one getLabel and getValue, they are all three different